# vuejs table router-link tag a

Tags: vue.js, routerlink

I want to add a router link to my table, everything is ok until here, but there is a situation like this. I want it to be displayed as a href.
Table gets corrupted when I do router tag="a"
When I set the router tag="tr", there is no problem, but the user may want to open that page by right-clicking the mouse and open a new window. so I would be happy if you could explain as an example how I can proceed. Thank you from now.

```js
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        userList: [
            {
                id: 1,
                name: "Prem",
                age: 18,
                status: "close",
                gender: "male",
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                name: "Chandu",
                status: "close",
                age: 20,
                gender: "female",
            },
            {
                id: 3,
                name: "Shravya",
                status: "open",
                age: 35,
                gender: "female",
            },
            {
                id: 4,
                name: "Shravya",
                status: "blocked",
                age: 35,
                gender: "female",
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

```css
table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #dddddd;
}

.dropdown-submenu {
    position: relative;
}

.dropdown-submenu .dropdown-menu {
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
    margin-top: -1px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router@2.0.0/dist/vue-router.js"></script>

<div id="app">
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Gender</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <router-link
        tag="tr"
        v-for="(user, i) in userList" :key="i"
        :to="{ name: 'UserDetail', params: { id:user.id }}"
        >
            <td>{{ user.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ user.age }}</td>
            <td>{{ user.status }}</td>
            <td>{{ user.gender }}</td>
    </router-link>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're trying to do wont work, as a table has a set structure, which doesn't allow for an `<a>` tag to be a child of `<tbody>`.

What you instead can do is use `position: absolute` to "stretch" your link to the entire row, basically placing it above all the other content. Just be aware that doing so will cancel out all other interactive content within your table. Like buttons and inputs.

I've copied the class/css from [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/utilities/stretched-link/), but it should work even if you aren't using it.

Just remember to place `position: relative;` on your `<tr>` so the link will be properly contained within each row.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      userList: [{
          id: 1,
          name: "Prem",
          age: 18,
          status: "close",
          gender: "male",
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: "Chandu",
          status: "close",
          age: 20,
          gender: "female",
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          name: "Shravya",
          status: "open",
          age: 35,
          gender: "female",
        }
      ]
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.stretched-link::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
  content: "";
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

.position-relative {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.14/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app" style="padding: 1rem;">
  <table class="table table-hover table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Gender</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="(user, i) in userList" class="position-relative">
        <td>{{ user.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ user.age }}</td>
        <td>{{ user.status }}</td>
        <td>
          {{ user.gender }}
          <!-- This can be placed in any of the <td>'s -->
          <a class="stretched-link" :href="`#${user.id}`"></a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this problem just occurres, because you are trying to use an `<a>` tag as a wrapper for your `<td>` instead of the `<tr>`.

Maybe instead you add another `<td>` to your table to display the `UserDetail` there. This could be something like this:

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>Age</th>
  <th>Status</th>
  <th>Gender</th>
  <th>Details</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr v-for="(user, i) in userList" :key="i">
  <td>{{ user.name }}</td>
  <td>{{ user.age }}</td>
  <td>{{ user.status }}</td>
  <td>{{ user.gender }}</td>
  <td>
    <router-link
        tag="a"
        :to="{ name: 'UserDetail', params: { id:user.id }}"
    >
      Show Details
    </router-link>
  </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I know how to do it this way too :) if you're aware, I want a href for the whole "tr".

Comment: @SelaminkoElam That is not possible. Please have a look at: [The Table element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table). A `<table>` has a fixed structure and as you see in your example, you need to keep it.